# Bootstrap holder.js wont display more than 1 image in the same span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, holder.js

Below is my code, the problem is that no matter what i do that second holder.js image refuses display. its as if bootsrap has a 1 holder.js thumb per span rule or something?

```
<div class="span4">
                <div class="pannel">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Request as Familiar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Request as Friend</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block btn-disabled">Add to Public</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Send Message</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Block</button>


                <div class="pannel">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: Was you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with rendering two placeholders in one parent. Make sure the source of the second image is changed using Dev Tools. If it is, there's a CSS rule preventing the second image from showing up; if it isn't, then the problem is with Holder.